# Create img tag with help of HTML helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work on MVC  5 project I am new to MVC technology.

I need to create img element and text according to my culture value, here the code in view:

```
@{
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
 }
```

The culture value keeps the current culture.

Here html that showing current culture by displaying flag and text:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle no-text-underline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/no.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" />Norsk</a>
```

When user select another language postback occures and **culture** value change accroding to user selection.After a postback occured the html above should display flag  and a text accroding to user selection.

For example if user selected english the **culture** element is "en" and the html is:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle no-text-underline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" />English</a>
```

I guess to implement it I need to generate img tag with help of razor html helper.

So my question is how can I generate img tag using html.helper?

Comment: A `HtmlHelper` is not necessary. You can just use `<a ..   />@culture</a>` for example

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need to display not only  tax but also an img element that have src attribute to specific flag

Comment: I assume the html you have shown is wrong (that `id` attribute makes no sense and I assume that is supposed to be the `src` attribute?). You just need to pass the path for the image to the model (view a view model property or a `ViewBag` property = e.g. `src="@View.ImagePath"`

Comment: Yes I had mistake with id and src attributes, fixed it.thanks :)

Comment: The element is on _Layout.chtml page so I have problem to use ViewBag, I dont have a controller for _Layout.chtml

Comment: You can still pass it via `ViewBag`, but what you should be doing is using `@Html.Action(..)` in the layout to call a server method that returns a partial view of the html.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks it helded me!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

> 1. add some static class for html helpers
> 2. reference it in cshtml file so that it will be visible

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayFlag(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
        var imgSrc = string.Format("/assets/images/flags/{0}.png", culture);
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("img");
        tag.AddCssClass("flag-lang");
        tag.MergeAttribute("src", imgSrc);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

> 3. And in cshtml file use it like this

```
@Html.DisplayFlag()
```

Have not tested it but it should work